# What is Olympic, Frontier and Morden?

Tags: network, testnets, networkid, releases

I see some clients accept the command line argument `--frontier` or `--olympic`. Is 'Frontier' more than just a name? What does it stand for?

And how does it differ from 'Olympic' and 'Morden'? What are they?