# Sync very slow on testnet after block around 589000

Tags: synchronization, testnets

For the past few days testnet is not working properly. As of now sync is very slow and all the testnet ether is lost. I came to know all this is because of some spamming attack. Did the steps suggested [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12589/geth-or-mist-do-not-sync-any-more/12590#12590). But of not much use. My testnet chain is at 589298 and sync is at around 15 sec for each block.

what steps to do, so that testnet will start working fine.