# Is Ropsten testnet dead?

Tags: testnets, ropsten, kovan

I am using the Ropsten testnet but it is stuck syncing only one block at a time around block 589000. How should i approach this? Just let it keep syncing? delete the whole blockchain and redownload it? or do I have to change to the Kovan testnet? I am looking for a Geth solution to the problem, not parity

Comment: It would appear the consensus starting to form is that it's dead. The current alternative would be to switch to Kovan on Parity. http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12816/52

Comment: If i am not mistaken Parity is like Geth but different implementation. And there is no solution using Geth?

Comment: There's a proposal for a Geth equivalent, here (though it's not implemented yet): https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225

Comment: There is no geth solution yet.