# From Metamask to Ethereum Wallet

Tags: wallets, metamask

I've created an Account on Ropsten Testnet with MetaMask, and I've on some test-ether and developed some smartcontracts.
Now I want to export my account on Ethereum Wallet, so I've exported the private key with metamask and imported on geth with command:

```
geth account import C:\MYFILEWITHPRIVETEKEYONIT.txt
```

But when I open the Ethereum Wallet and set it on Testnet, i see my account address but with no ether on it.
I've noticed that in Etehereum Wallet the account imported has in the name (Etherbase). 
So i think that it has not been correctly imported.

What's wrong with? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth your time to know that **Ropsten is dead, avoid using it :** [Ropsten testnet is under kind of attack? What can we do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do)

Your problem may be less to do with importing your private key into Ethereum Wallet and more to do with Ropsten being unusable.

There is a new testnet that you can use : https://github.com/kovan-testnet/proposal