# Node running on testnet doesn't match etherscan explorer

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, testnets, ropsten, forks

Two of my nodes running geth version 1.5.3 have been working great on testnet since 24th November 2016 by using this command:

```
geth --rpc --datadir /mydatadir/.ethereum/testnet --networkid 3
```

but recently they seem to be working on another chain or fork different from testnet.etherscan.io. Transactions and balances are different on my nodes from the public testnet explorer. Last transactions created by the nodes don't even exist on testnet.etherscan.io so I guess my nodes are working off the main testnet chain.

For example, the address 0xf28dafbfeb41bf32869c9d498da0d651d0206ed4 has **9,041** ethers according to testnet.etherscan.io but it has **10,121** according to my nodes:

```
https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xf28dafbfeb41bf32869c9d498da0d651d0206ed4
```

Besides, my nodes are reporting last block is **#667887** meanwhile testnet.etherscan.io says it is **#690562**

Has been there any kind of fork on testnet lately? Is parameter **networkid = 3** right to work on Ropsten testnet? Do I have to upgrade my node to work on the standard testnet chain again? Thx!

P.S.: After reading the 5 answers at [Ropsten testnet is under kind of attack? What can we do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do) my conclusion is Geth as of now cannot operate on last testnet Kovan. Right? So, only option seems to be to wait for new geth release or migrate my nodes to Parity, is that correct?

Comment: I'm afraid the testnet isn't currently usable. The plan will be to move to a new Geth-based testnet in the (hopefully near) future.

Comment: Does it mean it is not possible right now to work on etherscan testnet using geth clients?

Comment: That's correct. (Specifically, it's the _Ropsten_ testnet that you've been using thus far.) You have the option of moving to the Parity-based Kovan testnet, or waiting for the Geth alternative, Rinkeby. I'm unsure when the latter would be ready. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225

Comment: You can still use Parity's Kovan or a custom testnet in the meantime.

Comment: How to move to Kovan, just using networkid = 4, or something like that?

Comment: The Ropsten testnet seems to be behaving OK for me at the moment; Sync up with geth --fast, and make sure the block number matches the one you see on etherscan. Of course we never know when someone will decide to kill it again.