# Issue won't allow this transaction (Smart contract)

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx

•Windows 8
•Mist 0.8.9
•Tesnet

When I publish my crowdsale smart contract and try to send ethers,i have this warning[image: i need solve it]

Comment: try to provide more gas

Comment: I try to provide more gas 5,000,000 gas,the transaction not work

Comment: Could you share your contract code? Your function may for some reason be eating all the gas.

Comment: Could possibly be related to the ongoing testnet issue, somehow? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do

Comment: I have the same issue... is it really a testnet issue? because I can send the tokens to the account but not the ethers. When I try to send the ethers it shows up this message and if I try it fails it should be happening just if there where no enoguh tokens but there are... Which testnet should I use? or justdirectly the main network?