# Cannot use Mist for the testnet

Tags: mist

Please help me and it is quite urgent.

Started from last week, I could not use the Mist and Ethereum wallet on a window environment. I always uses the test-net, however, it just stop sync again. I have removed and reinstalled it. I tried the latest version. It stopped to sync once the initiation of the Application was finished (once the full testnet downloaded). Sometimes, it just re-downloaded everything again. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Without seeing any logs, and assuming you're talking about Ropsten, it might be related to this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do

Answer (score 1):

The Ropsten testnet is down. You can try using the Kovan testnet with Parity to run test contracts. Alternatively, you can setup your own testnet by running geth with the following options and then restarting your Mist browser:

```
geth --dev --datadir ~/.ethereum/privatenet --ipcpath ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc --networkid 43 --rpc --rpcapi web3,net,eth,personal --rpccorsdomain "**" --mine
```

Comment: I have heard much time about running geth. However, I do not know how to run it. Can you help me? Thank a lot.