# Are there any bootnodes for the revived Ropsten testnet?

Tags: synchronization, testnets, ropsten

After Ropsten is revived from [the attack](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do?rq=1), I tried syncing with `geth --testnet removedb && geth --testnet --fast` but I got inconsistent results every time.

Currently, `eth.getBlock('latest').number` returns ~963k where as https://ropsten.etherscan.io/ shows the latest block as ~834k. Am I connected to peers that are still running the attacked Ropsten? Are there trusted bootnodes for the new testnet?

I'm using Geth version `1.6.0-stable`.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`ethereum/ropsten`](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten), the bootnodes are:

- `enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303`
- `enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303`

Also, update your `geth`. [The latest version can be found here.](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases)