# Parity unable to deploy contract on ropsten

Tags: parity

I have running instance using parity: `parity --chain=ropsten --author=0x00c62AA7449864C21E5250533577ec628849dAE2 --rpcapi=web3,eth,personal --jsonrpc-interface=127.0.0.1 --jsonrpc-port=8545 --jsonrpc-cors=https://remix.ethereum.org` and faced strange issue already for 2 days: I cannot deploy contract and send funds to anywhere from my account.

When deploying contract Parity UI always shows "waiting for confirmations". I dropped previous account, removed all databases and configurations, started node again, synced and created new account. Then mined couple of ethers. Now contract deployment explicitly failed with message "The contract deployment failed: Contract not deployed, getCode returned 0x".

All contracts are developed in the Parity editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by incomplete local node synchronization. After sync finished problem was gone.

Comment: Yes, the client does not know that your contract is deployed unless it sees the block which includes this transaction. And this only happens when it's fully synchronized.

Answer (score -1):

I think Ropsten is dead as per this post: [Ropsten testnet is under kind of attack? What can we do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do/12551).  There are instructions for using the Kovan testnet in that same post.

Comment: Nope. I checked on Kovan and got the same results.

Comment: I think you have to go through some sort of a process to join Kovan. You can't just start using it. Not 100% sure, though. Did you do that?

Comment: Why not? I remove previous database (`parity db kill`), then started Parity and specified `--chain=kovan` (more exact: `parity --chain=kovan --rpcapi=web3,eth,personal --jsonrpc-interface=127.0.0.1 --jsonrpc-port=8545 --jsonrpc-cors="*"`). Then asked for couple of KETH in gitter. That is all. I have account with non-zero balance and problems with funds transfer.

Comment: Thomas, why you decided that Rosten is dead? In the answer to the post I see that Ropsten is revived (and I mean exactly Ropsten revived net).

Comment: Yes, Ropsten was revived and is not dead.

Comment: Not sure why my answer is downvoted. The discussion here might inform: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225. Ropsten may or may not be revived, but there's not a lot to protect it from being attacked again.