# Ethereum Mentor Needed

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, parity

I have spent nearly two weeks trying to download and sync mist. A few days ago I changed to parity and had a bit more success and finally achieved 100% sync, however, I then switched to test-net and ran parity --chain ropsten which started off ok but 2 days later is still trying to sync the final 100 blocks. It appears now that I have some kind of parity geth conflict idk. I've pretty much lost my mind but really don't want to give up.  I have a feeling I am close and just missing some key understanding.
I have run so many different commands from reading blogs, posts and watching videos I have no idea what could be running in the background and conflicting. Is it best to start again? Any advice would be highly appreciated at this point.
Thanks

Comment: If you're worried about conflicts between software, if you have the RAM and disk space, it might help to run things in a virtual machine such as one in VirtualBox. You can just blow away the whole virtual machine if things stop working or restore to a snapshot. It also means you're less likely to do things like mix up the main Ethereum chain and a test net chain.

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't give up. If you've made it this far, you're well on your way.
2. Ropston is constantly under attack and according to this post
   ([Ropsten testnet is under kind of attack? What can we do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do/12551))
   is now considered dead.
3. Parity has a replacement that is called Kovan. Instructions for using Kovan are at the same link.
4. Don't despair. Everyone has these same problems and there are those who will help.

Comment: Ropsten has been revived. A lot of beta Dapps are hosted on Ropsten these days.

Comment: It's my understanding that because Ropsten has many less miners, it is much easier to attack. It may be revived, but the fact that it needs to be revived every now and then is the problem. Kovan requires Proof of Authority. It's not decentralized, but is less easily attacked. And, it's a testnet, so not being decentralized is okay.

Comment: ok thanks for the encouragement. i am running kovan with the parity browser now so I'll see how that goes but appears to be much faster already