# Is there any lifespan of data on Rinkeby testnet?

Tags: contract-development, testnets, rinkeby, public-key, database

I read that there are pre-autorized nodes which creates blocks on rinkeby testnet.
If developers keep publishing smart contract and do transactions for testing purpose isn't the size of testnet will be huge after a time?
My question is for all testnet.
Is there any lifespan of data that after some time data will delete automatically?

Answer (score 3):

> I read that there are pre-autorized nodes which creates blocks on rinkeby testnet.

Correct. It's a proof of authority (PoA) network, where certain nodes have the authority to create new blocks.

> If developers keep publishing smart contract and do transactions for testing purpose isn't the size of testnet will be huge after a time?

"Huge" is a relative term, but yes, the size of the state data will continue to increase. I'm assuming the nodes running the network are sufficiently endowed to cater for this happening. Anyone else wanting to run a node should take this into account.

> My question is for all testnet. Is there any lifespan of data that after some time data will delete automatically?

There's is no predetermined lifespan, but it should be assumed that the testnets could go down at any time for whatever reason. The original testnet, Morden, and the first iteration of its replacement, Ropsten, were both taken down due to spam attacks.

The Rinkeby PoA network was created as a potential solution to this:

- Only authorised nodes can create new blocks, meaning no other nodes can be awarded the mining rewards.
- Testnet ether is only available via the [authenticated faucet](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/).

These two factors go towards preventing anyone from accumulating enough testnet ether to launch a DoS/spam attack. Even with these protections in place, it shouldn't be assumed that the network is bulletproof.

> My question is for all testnet.

The remaining PoW testnets may still be susceptible to spam attacks.

([Ropsten testnet is under kind of attack? What can we do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do))

Comment: Thanks Richard for the explanation. Your answer cleared my doubts. Can you please suggest which site i should follow which gives detailed/deep explanation of Ethereum Blockchain or related to it?

Comment: There's lots out there :-) This is a pretty good long-form article to begin with. It should give you a good general overview, and an idea of which specific topics you'd like to read more about. [How does Ethereum work, anyway?](https://medium.com/@preethikasireddy/how-does-ethereum-work-anyway-22d1df506369)