# Is necesary pass a Dapp to mainnet or in testnet is ok for a production smart contract process?

Tags: ether, testnets, mainnet, test

Because the client Dapp propietary don´t have real Ether, only Ropsten test Ether via faucet.ropsten.be/
is necesary buy Real Ether to preserve smart contracts in ethereum or in Ropsten testnetwok is possible have a production Dapp? excuse me i´m a new Ethereum developer

Comment: Hi! You might want to see if this Q&A answers your question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/91638/27270