# geth connect to TEST-NET

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets

When I connect to geth with

```
geth console
```

it automatically connects to Main Network. I would like to connect TEST-NET. How I could connect to TEST-NET with geth?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to launch geth console by giving "testnet" or "rinkeby" as an argument -

```
--testnet    Ropsten network: pre-configured proof-of-work test network
--rinkeby    Rinkeby network: pre-configured proof-of-authority test network
```

There are other parameters/arguments available as well, which you may find worth taking a look at, please check this [link](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) for more details.

Also see [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10313/26539) for the differences between the various test nets.

Comment: thanks, It worked. For interactive mode I used "geth --testnet console"

Comment: Which network is this on etherscan?

Comment: @JustinThomas Ropsten, Rinkeby and Mainnet have their own etherscan