# How to call smart contract from different networks?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets

I have two ethereum private networks, each with a smart contract deployed.
for example network.A and network.B

Now how can smart contract of network.A calls smart contract functions of network.B?

Comment: Short answer: smart contracts cannot call other smart contracts from different networks. You would need to rely on externally owned accounts to make calls and validate signatures and data.

Comment: The usual solution is to implement some sort of bridge between the blockchains. See here for something similar between ERC20 tokens https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99110/bridge-between-ethereum-networks.

Comment: yes, How can I implement my bridge? Can you give me some code